# My android app stops unexpectedly when I run in on the emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, mobile

I am using Eclypse and PhoneGap to build a mobile application for some reason, when I try to create new projects a message pops up that says "Android SDK Content Loader encountered a problem". If I proceed and create my project when I run on the emulator it says that the "unfortunately,  has stopped." I am not sure what the problem is, I am able to open old projects. Also, I don't know if the warning message I get at the beginning is related to the error on the emulator but decided to include it just in case.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample.project"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:name=".MyPhoneGapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete all your AVD files from your root folder or by AVD manager if you are able to get in. Then, restart Eclipse.

Comment: where would I usually find those files? Also, one of my applications began opening, but others are still not functioning quite right. Thanks for responding btw.

Comment: No problem, you can find the files at `c:\users\android\avd`. Sometimes the emulators can get pretty weird and out of nowhere they stop working correctly. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks once again, that solved the problem. Now my apps open pretty well on the virtual device.